# AngularJs, download large files

Tags: angularjs, download, large-files

I need to download a large file from angular. I have a link and when the client click, the file must be downloaded.
Code in Controller:

```
$scope.download = function(id, type){
    LogService.getLogFile(id, type)  //service call endpoint of backend
                    .then(function (data) {  

                        var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/csv;charset=utf-8'});
                        var fileURL = $window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        a.href = fileURL;
                        a.download = fileName;
                        a.click();
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        //error
                    });
}
```

It works for small files(300Mb) but with large files (800Mb) don't work.
I would need to download files until 4Gb. And with the main browser (Chrome, Mozilla and Safari). Because I saw in [jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/)
 a solution (Not tested) but only for Chrome and Opera.

I use Node Js in backend, the code is:

```
function getFile(req, res){

     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
     res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');

     var filePath = '....'; //PATH 
     var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

     readStream.pipe(res);

    })
    .catch(function () {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved it adding token to url and request to api.

html:

```
<a ng-click="downloadFile('attributes')" ng-if="log.path_attributes_file">download</a>
```

Controller, add to url param 'token'.

```
//Download File
        $scope.downloadFile = function downloadFile(type) {
            window.location.href = '/api/logs/' + $scope.log._id +'/' + type + '?token=' + $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
        }
```

app.js in Node Js, for getting token from url. By default only take from header. I use 'express-jwt' module. And the token is: 'Bearer 23f334f...token...dafafad'

```
    app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret ,getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.query.token.split(' ')[1];
    }
    return null;
}}).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));
```

Handler request in Node JS. 'nameFile' is the name of file downloaded and 'pathFile' is the path where the file is.

```
function getFile(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');
    res.attachment(nameFile);
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathFile));
}
```

Comment: Is it secure to send token in url as visible?